# Why does Skyrim crash my system when I open my map?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, technical-issues

I came upon a very frustrating problem while trying to play Skyrim.
[Similar problems](http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/456889-skyrim-complete-pc-crashes/) were discussed quite a lot (157 forum pages!), but I don't seem to find any solution to this.

**Problem itself:**

When I open world map in Skyrim with <kbd>M</kbd> key my system crashes almost instantly. Video card stops working ("No signal" on monitor), after that sound freezes and loops. Only hard reset works to recover my system, so the OS must have crashed too (but I am not able to check BSOD due to video not working)

A crash with exactly the same symptoms happened when I was trying to play Red Faction: Armageddon. Had no problems until the scene where you have to protect a convoy in a battlesuit on some flying platform. My system crashed every time during that scene,and I wasn't able to proceed.

**System details:**

- Windows 7 x64
- Core i5 @3.4 GGhz
- 16 Gb DDR3
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 650 Ti
- Skyrim with all 3 DLCs, Legendary Edition, Steam

I am pretty sure that my hardware is fine since I've played a lot of demanding games and had this kind of problem with only 2 of them in very specific circumstances. Even Skyrim runs fine for hours unless I open the map.
I blame the interaction between application and video driver. *Crash is not random, it happens after specific actions.* Also, it isn't the application that crashes, but rather the whole system.

**More info:**

- I am using Unofficial Skyrim Patch mods from Nexus
- I am using SKSE and ENB
- I am using a lot of other mods
- Disabling all mods listed above does not solve this problem
- I have no "bloodSplatter" setting in my config
- My system is not overheating, both CPU and GPU.
- Video drivers are most recent, however I tried older(332 and 314) versions without success.

Can someone suggest anything on how to solve this? I've seen a lot of threads all over the internet, but I've seen no actual solutions.

Comment: Sounds like something strange is going on with your video card.  I'd say corrupted drivers, but you've tried other ones.  It could be the video card is just showing its age.

Comment: Have you checked if the crash still occurs when you use a mod for the worldmap?

Also, if what you are experiencing is a blue screen, the you will find a memory dump file in C:\Windows\Minidump.

Comment: I hear there's a nice graphics card farm near your town where old cards can live. It's cool and quiet so they never have to worry about overheating.

Comment: @MichaelK I have tried this mod: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/4929/

Comment: @Frank Maybe age, but the card is not that old (about 2 years) and handles heavy games like Crysis 3 on Max without issues.

Comment: @MichaelK I don't think adding another mod on top of the others will help

Comment: Try a fresh install on another partition or folder and see if the problem still happens. If it's ok, you could just merge you save files to this new install and delete the old one and reinstall all mods too.

Comment: Laptop or Desktop?

Comment: @Brok3n Desktop

Comment: @MichaelK I don't know why, but Minidump folder is empty.

Comment: Contacted Nvidia support, they told me to reinstall Windows as there are no other options.

Comment: VTC as too broad. "Many mods" can cause many issues. This question fits the criteria that made modded Minecraft crashes off-topic.

Comment: @MrLemon If you bother to read the question, it crashes even without mods. However, question can be closed indeed, since the problem appears in other games, so it must be related to hardware/driver issues... Still I was not able to pinpoint the probles, so I've just stopped playing games and plan to replace videocard.

Answer (score -1):

This is due to a weird glitch if the below lines are added to skyrim ini:

[ScreenSplatter]
bBloodSplatterEnabled=0

I removed them and fixed the problem for me. I now use a mod to remove blood from screen
(I actually only use 2 files from this mod - see post/comments section of nexus for the below mod):
http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/107/?

Comment: Blood splatter does not effect opening maps bug. -1